# How to combine a Kendo Hierarchical Grid with a kendoSortable?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo hierarchical grid and I want to be able to sort the "outer" grid.  I get the sort to work, but the details grid doesn't move with its parent.

My grid:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: [{
            Name: "Hilari",
            prodID: 1
        }, {
            Name: "Carlo",
            prodID: 2
        }, {
            Name: "Kelcie",
            prodID: 3
        }],
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Name: {
                        type: "string"
                    },
                    prodID: {
                        type: "number"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "Name"
    }],
    detailInit: detailInit
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

The sortable:

```
grid.table.kendoSortable({
    filter: ">tbody >tr",
    hint: $.noop,
    cursor: "move",
    placeholder: function (element) {
        return element.clone().addClass("k-state-hover").css("opacity", 0.65);
    },
    container: "#grid tbody",
    change: function (e) {
        //     var skip = grid.dataSource.skip(),
        //     oldIndex = e.oldIndex + skip,
        //     newIndex = e.newIndex + skip,
        //     data = grid.dataSource.data(),
        //     dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));

        //     grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
        //     grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);

    }
});
```

Detail init:

```
function detailInit(e) {
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: [{
                prodID: 1,
                Pet: "Dog"
            }, {
                prodID: 1,
                Pet: "Cat"
            }, {
                prodID: 1,
                Pet: "Fish"
            }, {
                prodID: 2,
                Pet: "Bird"
            }, {
                prodID: 2,
                Pet: "Ferret"
            }, {
                prodID: 3,
                Pet: "Snake"
            }, {
                prodID: 3,
                Pet: "Frog"
            }],
            filter: {
                field: "prodID",
                operator: "eq",
                value: e.data.prodID
            }
        },
        columns: [{
            field: "Pet"
        }]
    });
}
```

Here is a JSBin that shows my issue:
http://jsbin.com/fizup/1/edit

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Hilari

Comment: working demos are great, but please make sure to post your code as part of the question as well so the question still makes sense in case the off-site content is lost

Answer (score 2):

You are right. If you check the generated HTML you will see that child grid is actually another row in the parent grid.

Sortable moves a row but does not check if the next row is actually part of the parent Grid or the Child grid.

You might do some tricks as collapse the parent before start moving, then sort it normally and finally expand it back.

As a first approach, try defining in your `kendoSortable` the following event handlers:

```
start : function(e) {
    // collapse master row when starting to move
    grid.collapseRow(e.item);
},
change: function(e) {
    // expand it back
    grid.expandRow(e.item);
}
```

See it here: http://jsbin.com/wakod/1/

Then you can improve the solution by checking in `start` if the master row was actually expanded and in `change` expand it only if in `start` you detected it as expanded.

```
start : function(e) {
    grid.isExpanded = $("a.k-minus", e.item).length > 0;
    grid.collapseRow(e.item);
},
change: function(e) {
    if (grid.isExpanded) {
        grid.expandRow(e.item);
    }
}
```

See it here: http://jsbin.com/wakod/2/

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  I like the suggestions you made, but they still don't help the fact that the inner grids are not being moved along with the parent grids.  The first dropdown has Dog, Cat, and Fish.  When you move that person to the bottom, the new top person now has Dog, Cat, and Fish even though they should have been moved with the person that was moved.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust the change handler of the sortable slightly to fix the following issues:

- `dataSource.skip()` can return `undefined`
- after you insert the dragged row in the correct position, you need to find the `<tr>` to expand again (`e.item` is no longer valid because the grid refreshed after the insert)

Here's how you could do it:

```
change: function (e) {
    var skip = grid.dataSource.skip() || 0,
        oldIndex = e.oldIndex + skip,
        newIndex = e.newIndex + skip,
        uid = e.item.data("uid"),
        dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(uid),
        rowToExpand;

    grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
    grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);

    if (grid.isExpanded) {
        rowToExpand = $(grid.tbody).find("tr[data-uid=" + uid + "]");
        grid.expandRow(rowToExpand);
    }
}
```

([demo](http://jsbin.com/cosop/2), based on OnaBai's solution)